# Hugo dynamic navbar menu item for sign in, sign out

Tags: hugo

I would like to add an item to my navbar that changes based on whether the user is signed in or signed out. This is a very common feature--this website has it in the upper right. Currently the best I can do is add static **Sign In** and **Sign Out** items to the navbar.

For example, I might provide a JavaScript function whose return value determines the menu item.

Please note that I already have authentication working. Here I am just asking how to improve on my static **Sign In** and **Sign Out** items to the Hugo navbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to have the sign in and sign out items on the nav bar with a css class that hides them:

```
.hidden{
   display: none;
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Then in your JS auth code show the relevant one

```
const signInButton = document.getGelementById('sign-in-button');
const signOutButton = document.getGelementById('sign-out-button');

if(userIsSignedIn()){
    signInButton.classList.add('hidden');
    signOutButton.classList.remove('hidden');
}else{
    signInButton.classList.remove('hidden');
    signOutButton.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Another way would be to have no items for sign in/out in the nav bar and add them with JS

```
const navBar = document.getGelementById('nav-bar');

if(userIsSignedIn()){
    addButton('sign-in', 'Sign Out');
    removeButton('sign-out');
}else{
    addButton('sign-out', 'Sign Out');
    removeButton('sign-in');
}
    
function addButton(id, value) {
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.id = id;
    btn.innerText = value;
    
    if(event.target.id == 'sign-in'){
        btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{            
                signIn();
        });
    }else if(event.target.id == 'sign-out'){
        btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{            
                signOut();
        });
    }

    navBar.append(btn);
}   


function removeButton(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem){
        elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
}
```

Though that might be a bit complicated for no real extra benefit.